# The document “X” could not be autosaved. You don’t have permission

Tags: macos, osx-server, permission, xserve

I have a Mac OSX Lion file share over the AFP protocol in our office and users are having trouble saving to it. Here's the process:

1. Open an existing file on the server
2. Make changes
3. Save changes, error: "The document “X” could not be autosaved. You don’t have permission."

Additional notes:

Users cannot save new files directly to the server (same permissions error); however, they can save the file to their desktop first and then drag it to the server in the same location.

Here is a print out of the permissions for that particular directory:

[image]

The permissions appear to be wide open...*right?*

For what it's worth, here is a screenshot of the error:

[image]

Any ideas what I can do to resolve this issue?

Comment: Are there any flags on the directory, and what xattrs does it have? Try `ls -leO@d` (and be sure to run that on the server, not a client).

Answer (score 1):

Which place do you have users created on the server?  Are they here:
[image]

Or are they here:
[image]

The important question is are they local users (which will give you the behavior you have) or are they local NETWORK users?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. They are created in server.app, but mine looks slightly different than yours. Remember, I'm on 10.7 server: http://cl.ly/image/003A3u1Z3M2F

Comment: It's all I had to screen shot, sorry.  Is only one person opening a file at a time?  Or are three or four (multiple users) opening the same file?

Comment: I've tried it in both scenarios. Same issue.

Comment: I tried, sorry to have wasted your time.  At least you know something it's not.