# Random "The document could not be autosaved. You don't have permission." messages despite having permissions

Tags: permission, file, autosave

Since I got a new computer, I'm getting the following message all the time in TeXShop (same version I had on my old computer):

> The document could not be autosaved. You don't have permission.

This means my documents aren't being autosaved for some reason. But it gets worse. When I try to save a document, a lot of the time I get the following message:

> The document "[documentname]" could not be saved. The file is locked. Do you want to save your changes to it anyway?

If I click on "Save anyway", I get the following message:

> You don't have permission to save the file "[documentname]" in the folder "[foldername]". To view or change permissions, select the item in the Finder and choose File > Get Info.

I have all of my personal documents on custom folders in my iCloud Drive. All of my folders and the documents therein have permissions set up such that I can read and write. (The answers [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/37238/the-document-x-could-not-be-saved-you-don-t-have-permission) and [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/70421/the-document-x-could-not-be-autosaved-you-don-t-have-permission) are therefore useless to me.)

I've also checked the permissions of ~/Library/"Autosave Information", and I can read and write there as well.

I didn't have this problem *with the same files* on my old computer. I migrated everything to my new computer with Time Machine, which shouldn't mess with permissions, but, as stated above, I've checked my permissions anyway and they're fine.

I don't know whether the problem is a Monterey issue (I had Catalina on my old computer), an Apple-Silicon issue (current computer is M1 Max, previous computer was Intel) or something else.

Please help.

Comment: This is likely an issue with the app you're using. Can you provide information on the app?

Comment: Hah! I can't believe I didn't specify the app in question. Silly me! I'll edit my question now to include this info.

Answer (score -1):

I think this should work.
Go to **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Full Disk Access**  then unlock the small lock at the bottom left and authorize the app you want.

p.s.: Remember to lock it again after you finish ;-)

Comment: Thanks, just authorised the app, will let you know how it goes.